# Flipping coins probability of $6$ flips having more heads than $5$ flips.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I have $6$ fair coins and you have $5$ fair coins. We both flip our own coins and observe the number of heads we each have. What is the probability that I have more heads than you?

Not sure how to start this, any help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{6} \binom{6}{i}p^i(1-p)^{6-i}(\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\binom{5}{j}p^j(1-p)^{5-j})$$

The term in the first sum gives $\Pr(i\text{ heads out of 6 flips})$. The second sum is $\Pr(\text{strictly less than $i$ heads out of 5 flips})$. Then we use the sum out in front to add up all this probability for each $i$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be the number of heads in my 5 flips.

Let $Y$ be the number of heads in the first 5 of your 6 flips, and $Z$ be the number of heads from the flip of the sixth coin.

The probability that you have more heads than me is, by the Law of Total Probability

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(Y+Z > X) & = \mathsf P(Y>X\mid Z=0) \mathsf P(Z=0) + \mathsf P(Y\geq X\mid Z=1)\mathsf P(Z=1)
\end{align}$$

Now, use the fact that $X,Y,Z$ are mutually independent, and further that $X$ and $Y$ are identically and independently distributed.

(**Hint:** use the law of complements to find symmetry)

Answer (score 1):

An answer using generating functions:

$$G(x)=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{2}\right)^6 \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2 \
x}\right)^5$$

Expanding that I get:

$$\frac{231}{1024}+\frac{1}{2048 x^5}+\frac{11}{2048 \
x^4}+\frac{55}{2048 x^3}+\frac{165}{2048 x^2}+\frac{165}{1024 \
x}+\frac{231 x}{1024}+\frac{165 x^2}{1024}+\frac{165 \
x^3}{2048}+\frac{55 x^4}{2048}+\frac{11 x^5}{2048}+\frac{x^6}{2048}$$

Use only the terms that have positive powers of x:

$$\frac{231 x}{1024}+\frac{165 x^2}{1024}+\frac{165 x^3}{2048}+\frac{55 \
x^4}{2048}+\frac{11 x^5}{2048}+\frac{x^6}{2048}$$

Enter x = 1 to clear out the x variable and sum the terms.

$$ \frac{231}{1024}+\frac{165}{1024}+\frac{165}{2048}+\frac{55}{2048}+
\frac{11}{2048}+\frac{1}{2048}=\frac{1}{2} $$

The answer is $ \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Using a super simple approach, the only advantage the $6$ coin person has is the one "extra" coin.  So it would be similar to both of them each giving up $5$ coins and one person just flipping the one remaining coin.  Half the time that person would have more "heads" ($1$ vs. $0$) so the probability is $\frac 1 2$.

Comment: Don't I get any credit for having the simplest answer here?

Comment: Would the same argument work if I have two more coins than you?  Would it work if the coins have heads probability different from 0.5?

Comment: The original question did not address those "concerns" so no need to answer those hypotheticals.

Comment: The reason to consider them is it seems too good to be true that such a simple argument will work; stretching it a bit may identify flaws.  For example, the argument doesn't look like it relies on the coins having heads probability 1/2, so we should be able to replace 1/2 with an arbitrary $p$ in the last line.  If so, that suggests there's a problem: $p$ is not the right answer except when $p=\frac{1}{2}.$  There are also issues extending the argument to the case of a two-coin advantage: the right answer is not simply the probability of getting one or more heads on the extra coins.

Comment: Yes, but in the case of the two-coin advantage, the correct answer (for 5 and 7 coins) is about 61%, not 75%.  The correct answer for $n$ and $n+2$ coins approaches 50% as $n$ approaches infinity.  This makes sense: if you flip 1,000,000 coins and I flip 1,000,002 coins, we'll both get about 500,000 heads with a standard deviation of about 500 coins.  Since 500 is large compared with 2, the extra coins don't help much.

Comment: Will Orrick:  You appear to be correct.  I ran a simulation of $1,000,000$ trials of the $7$ vs. $5$ fair coins and the person with the $7$ coins had more heads than the other person about $61.3$% of the time, not $75$%.  I sit corrected for the +$2$ coin situation.

Comment: An argument very close to the one given by Graham Kemp goes like this: consider the six vs. five case.  If we are tied after five tosses then I have a 50% chance of pulling ahead on the sixth toss; if we are not tied after five tosses then there is a 50% chance that I am ahead, in which case the sixth toss doesn't matter, and a 50% chance that you are ahead, in which case the sixth toss still doesn't matter since I can at best equal but no exceed your heads total.  Either way, I come out ahead 50% of the time.  This argument doesn't work in the seven vs. five case: if we are tied ...

Comment: ... after five tosses then I have a 75% chance of pulling ahead; if we are not tied, then 50% of the time I am ahead (and will stay ahead); if you are ahead by 1, then I pull ahead 25% of the time, and if you are ahead by more than 1, I cannot pull ahead.  This makes it clear that the probability I come out ahead is less than 75%, but to compute it exactly, we need to make a detailed calculation like the one in user178543's answer: what is the probability of a tie? what is the probability you are ahead by 1?